# Is there a way to fix the compiler not finding specific openCV variables/functions?

Tags: c++, opencv

I just installed openCV 3.2.0 after a long hassle with it. I tried writing a program that loads an image, converts it to gray scale, writes it and then displays both. Problem is whenever I try running

> g++ main.cpp -o output `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

I get the following

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:14:27: error: ‘COLOR_BGR2GRAY’ was not declared in this scope
   cvtColor(image, gImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:27: note: suggested alternative: ‘CV_BGR2GRAY’
   cvtColor(image, gImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                           CV_BGR2GRAY
main.cpp:14:3: error: ‘cvtColor’ was not declared in this scope
   cvtColor(image, gImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
   ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:14:3: note: suggested alternative: ‘cvCvtColor’
   cvtColor(image, gImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
   ^~~~~~~~
   cvCvtColor
```

I am reading the openCV tutorial and I am reading it for my version, 3.2.0, and it is using the names I am trying to use.

This is my code:

```
#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main()
{
  Mat image = imread("test.jpeg", 1);
  Mat gImage;
  cvtColor(image, gImage, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

  imwrite("test_gray.jpeg", gImage);

  namedWindow("Display image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow("Display image", image);

  namedWindow("gray", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
  imshow("gray", gImage);

  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

And I tried running

> pkg-config --modversion opencv

to check if I had the correct version of opencv installed and it returned '3.2.0' as expected.
Also I am running Mint 19.1 if this is of any relevance (and I am a beginner so I am not very savvy with the things more advanced users might suggest/do)

Comment: isn't `pkg-config --cflags --libs` supposed to be in ticks ?

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes I had written it in ticks but forgot to escape it, edited it now

Comment: I think you are missing an include `#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>`, also you can use the opencv header which includes most of them `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

Comment: @api55 yeah that imgproc.hpp was all I needed, thanks! I was using the same includes they had on the official documentation/tutorial for my version, I wonder why they thought it worked then. Weird. Thanks again anyways.

Comment: I think it changed from version 3.4 -> 4.0 or 3.2 -> 3.4 not 100% sure, but for 3.2 it is like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
```

was all I needed. Wasn't written in the official tutorial's code so I didn't know I needed it.